# How to make a <p> not to inherit the <span> opacity style?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a white button with rounded corners and with a little transparency. The text should not be transparent. I tried to use `opacity: initial` for `<p>` style but it seems to not work. Take a look at my snippet to understand better.

```css
body {
  background-color: #264D38;
 }

.button {
 display: inline-block;
 width: 150px;
 border-radius: 2px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 background-color: #898989;
 opacity: 0.4;
 filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* Para IE8 e anteriores */
}

span.button > p {
 opacity: initial;
 padding: 10px;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

.button:hover {
 background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<body>
<a href="#"><span class="button"><p>BUY NOW</p></span></a>
</body>
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping a `<p>` with a `<span>` to begin with? Your markup will be invalid if you wrap block level elements with inline elements. If you need another element use another `<span>` or something else like `<strong>`, `<em>`, `<b>`, `<i>`, etc.

Comment: `<span>` elements represent phrasing content, and mechanically are used to group inline elements, as @hungerstar said. This is very bad practice. Please read up on HTML dom elements: [Span](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span), and [p](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) for starters.

Comment: Just to help emphasize the other two comments, this markup is invalid.

Comment: Sorry for my markup mistake, thanks for the info, I will correct right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opacity affects all children elements. Children can't have a 0% transparency, when a parent have 40%.

Other solution is setting only semi-transparent background.

```css
body {
    background-color: #264D38;
}

.button {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

span.button > p {
    padding: 10px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

.button:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <a href="#">
        <span class="button">
            <p>BUY NOW</p>
        </span>
    </a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use an [RGBA](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_color_rgba) value for the background colour instead of using opacity.

**Example**

```
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(137,137,137,.4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use a proper structure of the code. `span` is an inline type and must be in the `p` element, which is a block type, as @hungerstar says it will not be a valid markup.

Then you can do it like this, with `:before` pseudo element to set the background and absolute position of the `span` :

[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/ep3dx4t9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`RGBA`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgba) or [`HSLA`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#hsla) for your `background-color`. You can improve on your markup so it's no longer invalid (you're wrapping a block level element `<p>` with an inline element `<span>`). We now have one less element with the same results.

[Support chart](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-colors) for `rgba()` and `hsla()`.

```html
<a href="#"><span class="button">BUY NOW</span></a>
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #264D38;
 }
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 26px 0;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: rgba( 137, 137, 137, 0.4 );
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
.button:hover {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bqtkLhzb/).